# count number of lines in azure blob file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

We have a Microsoft Hdinsight cluster.
I would like to have a powershell one liner which helps to find the count of lines in a file present in azure blob. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you run powershell in HdInsight? I bet I can google a PS script within five minutes. Lets race

Comment: Here's a start. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084642/powershell-get-number-of-lines-of-big-large-file

Comment: oh.. except the blob makes it a little trickier. I don't know if there is a blob API that lets you do this.

Comment: Here's some hadoop native ways to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612867/how-to-count-lines-in-a-file-on-hdfs-command

Comment: I have checked in google and didn't find a one liner. A possible approach is to download the file into local system and get the count which I guess takes some time as i have around 30 files each with 1 GB

Answer (score 1):

The following should give what you want:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "ContainerName" -Blob "Blob" - | Measure-Object –Line
```